# Invisble reCAPTCHA 2.0 reCAPTCHA Token: null with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

So even in Google reCAPTCHA site it says:

> We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This
> is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see
> our developer site for more information.

And in console.log I get Token: null.

What have I done wrong here?

HTML:

```
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  <form id="yourFormId">
                    <div class="input-group input-group-outline mb-3">
                      <label class="form-label" id="nameLabel">Namn</label>
                      <input id="inputName" type="text" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group input-group-outline mb-3">
                      <label class="form-label" id="emailLabel">E-post</label>
                      <input id="inputEmail" type="email" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-group input-group-outline mb-3 position-relative">
                    <label class="form-label" id="passwordLabel">Lösenord</label>
                    <input id="inputPassword" type="password" class="form-control">
                
                </div>
                 
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <button id="create-newuser-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg bg-gradient-info btn-lg w-100 mt-4 mb-0">Skapa Konto</button>
                  </div>
                                        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my-site-key" data-callback="onRecaptchaSuccess" data-size="invisible"></div>
                </form>
      <script src="../sso/sign-up.js" type="module"></script>
```

/sso/sign-up.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        // Show labels when the page loads
        $("#nameLabel, #emailLabel, #passwordLabel").show();
        $("#warningMessage, #passwordLengthAlert, #success-message").hide();
    
        // Add event listeners to show/hide labels as the user types
        function toggleLabelVisibility(inputField, label) {
            if (inputField.val().length > 0) {
                label.hide();
            } else {
                label.show();
            }
        }
    
        $("#inputName").on("input", function () {
            toggleLabelVisibility($(this), $("#nameLabel"));
        });
    
        $("#inputEmail").on("input", function () {
            toggleLabelVisibility($(this), $("#emailLabel"));
        });
    
        $("#inputPassword").on("input", function () {
            toggleLabelVisibility($(this), $("#passwordLabel"));
    
            // Check password length and display alert if less than 6 characters
            var password = $(this).val();
            if (password.length < 6) {
                $("#passwordLengthAlert").show();
            } else {
                $("#passwordLengthAlert").hide();
            }
        });
    
        $("#create-newuser-button").click(function () {
            // Hide the warning message at the beginning of the validation logic
            $("#warningMessage").hide();

                 // Execute invisible reCAPTCHA with the callback
            grecaptcha.execute(undefined, { action: 'submit' }).then(onRecaptchaSuccess);
    
            var name = $("#inputName").val();
            var email = $("#inputEmail").val();
            var password = $("#inputPassword").val();
            var checkboxChecked = $("#flexCheckDefault").is(":checked");
    
            if (name.trim() === '' || email.trim() === '' || password.trim() === '' || !checkboxChecked || password.length < 6) {
                // Show the warning message or password length alert
                $("#warningMessage").show();
                $("#success-message").hide();
    
                // Auto-dismiss the warning message after 3 seconds
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#warningMessage").hide();
                }, 3000);
    
                return; // Stop further processing
            }

            // Create a new user in Firebase Auth
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(function (userCredential) {
                    // User creation was successful
                    var user = userCredential.user;

                    user.sendEmailVerification()
                        .then(function() {
                            console.log("Email verification sent");
                        })
                        .catch(function(error) {
                            console.error("Error sending email verification: ", error);
                        });

                    // Now, store additional user data in Firestore
                    return db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
                        uid: user.uid, // Store the uid
                        email: email,
                        password: password,
                        displayName: name,
                    });
                })
                .then(function () {
                    // Additional logic after Firestore write success
                    console.log("User data successfully written to Firestore!");

                    // Show the success message
                    $("#success-message").show();
                    console.log("About to show success message");

                    setTimeout(function() {
                    window.location.href = "/pages/home.html";
                }, 5000);

                    // Auto-dismiss the success message after 10 seconds
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#success-message").hide();
                    }, 10000);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // Handle errors during user creation or Firestore write
                    console.error("Error creating user or writing data to Firestore: ", error);

                    // Show the warning message and auto-dismiss after 3 seconds
                    $("#warningMessage").show();
                    $("#success-message").hide();

                    // Auto-dismiss the warning message after 3 seconds
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#warningMessage").hide();
                    }, 3000);
                });
        });
    });
    
    function onRecaptchaSuccess(token) {
        // Log the reCAPTCHA token to the console
        console.log("reCAPTCHA Token:", token);
    
        // Execute your authentication logic inside the promise chain
        firebase.auth().signInWithRecaptcha(token)
            .then(function (userCredential) {
                // Handle successful authentication
                var user = userCredential.user;
                console.log("Authentication successful:", user);
    
                // Now you can proceed with the rest of your logic
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // Handle authentication error
                console.error("Authentication error:", error);
            });
    }
```

Comment: And yes I have hidden the keys. 'my-site-key is placeholder'.

Comment: Also: ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: onRecaptchaSuccess